# Enable remote administration of computer using linux redhat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

how i can do this in linux redhat
2.  Enable remote administration of this computer from your own LAN for your own account only. Use a windows client to transfer files and perform administrations tasks.

Comment: Is your homework due?

Answer (score 1):

Both Redhat linux 2 and Redhat Enterprise linux 2 are ancient so I'm not sure you really mean either of those? There are lots of ways of doing this in Redhat systems generally though - You only really need PuTTY on the Windows system to remotely log in to a linux box, send files and execute commands but most people would like the communications to be more secure than that so they'd use rpm (the Redhat package manager) to install OpenSSH on the linux machine so that the sessions can be established securely.

`rpm -qi openssh` to query installation status.

`rpm -ivh openssh` to install.

A user will need to be created or exist previously on the linux box and if you need superuser privileges on the box for administration your user will need to be added to `/etc/sudoers` by root.

SSH can be restricted to certain users and subnets in its configuration file for whatever distro and version you have - something like

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

That should give you a rough idea about where to look. You have a bit of work ahead of you though if you're just beginning.